# Why is this consecutive not allowed

Tags: if-statement, swift2

I am trying to follow this appcoda GoogleMaps tutorial and converting to swift 2. I am really new to swift and having trouble understanding.

```
do {
   let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

   } catch let error as NSError {

      print("Error")
      completionHandler(status: "", success: false)

   }; else {
      // Get the response status.
      let status = dictionary["status"] as String

      if status == "OK" {
        let allResults = dictionary["results"] as Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
        self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]
```

I am getting the error before "else" where it first recommended a ";" because of consecutive statement but then it errors in the same place "expected expression". I swear I have done this before without errors. I am having trouble understanding why. Is it something to do with a poor set up of try, catch, do? Any insight appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you include some more lines prior to this section?  You can simplify them if need be.  But essentially you have an `else` with no matching `if`

Comment: Remove the semicolon and put the code on success before the `catch` scope

Comment: True, and also the semicolon shouldn't be there. Not before an `else` branch.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E.g. you could fix the trivial compile errors (like the wrong parenthesis) so we can paste your code into Xcode Playground and see the error you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

@pirateKyle

I think you should do this way

```
 do {
        let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
            // Get the response status.
            let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

        if status == "OK" {
            let allResults = dictionary["results"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
            self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

            // Keep the most important values.
            self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"] as! String
            let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"]as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
            self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lng"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
            self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lat"]as! NSNumber).doubleValue

            completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
        }
        else {
            completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
        }


    } catch let error as NSError {
        completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
    print(error)
    }
```